# How to draw graphic from .txt file (y-axis setting)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a graphic to show values in `.txt` file, and now I have problem setting y-axis format although I use the same commands as the commands for `.CSV` file. If I set the `y-lim` by using `my_y_ticks = np.arange(-100, 1000, 100)`, the interval is not `100`, besides it is hard to recogniz the y-axis values. I paste some original values from the `.txt`databank.

```
01/05/2016  00:01:00    313,000000  U   42491,000694    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:02:00    313,000000  U   42491,001389    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:03:00    313,000000  U   42491,002083    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:04:00    313,000000  U   42491,002778    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:05:00    313,000000  U   42491,003472    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:06:00    313,000000  U   42491,004167    -1,87   

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('WHV_Wasserstand_2016-2018.txt', sep = '\t') #open file
x = df.iloc[:,0] #choose values from txt file
y = df.iloc[:,2] #choose values from txt file
x = pd.to_datetime(x)   #transfer to date-time format
plt.ylim((-100,1000))
my_y_ticks = np.arange(-100, 1000, 100) #this code doesn't work!
plt.plot(x,y)   
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

And this is my actual result:

[image: actual result]

Comment: You will first need to make sure to combine the first two columns into one to have a datetime (with date *and* time). Then you need to be aware that the comma is not a decimal separator. So what you perceive as numbers are really just strings like `"Banana,Cherry"`. Convert them to actual numbers to make sure to see numeric values on the axis.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested, but something that immediately stands out is that your parameters for `np.arange()` will not yield an interval of 100 values. When given three values, `numpy.arange()` uses the first parameter as the start of the interval, the second as the end of the interval and the third as the "step," meaning the spacing between numbers in this interval. Your function will give you values like this:

```
>>> np.arange(-100,1000,100)
array([-100, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900])
```

It stops at 900 because the ending interval is exclusive. Consider if these are the values you want to pass into `my_y_ticks`